# How to create function that works take photo shoot+ save

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to create an iphone app that if you shoot using the camera it automatically save and shoot again until you click Done.

is that possible?

Comment: Do you have any sources on that? Coz I can't figure it out and Im a newbie on this technology. Plz thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `takePicture` method of [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). From the documentation:

> Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate the programmatic capture of a still image. This supports taking more than one picture without leaving the interface, but requires that you hide the default image picker controls.

Since you have to have the default controls hidden, you'll also want to look at `cameraOverlayView`, which lets you provide your own controls to use instead. That's where you can put your start and done buttons.